# What is my vertical reach?

Tags: dnd-5e, reach

I created a fighter which can jump very high, but I had difficulty determining how high I can exactly reach. I am a Goliath which is 8 feet tall (strength 20). Say my weapon has 5 feet reach.

Can I reach creatures which are 13 feet above the ground, while standing on the ground?

Comment: Related: [How far down can I attack when standing on the ceiling?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150255/52137), [At what point do you leave a creature's reach when moving vertically?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110725/52137), [If an enemy is just below a 10-foot-high ceiling, are they in melee range of a creature on the ground?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/147126/52137), [How do the height and reach of a monster such as a hydra work in combat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/140692/52137).

Comment: I know you can jump up and hit creatures. My question was about when you keep standing on the ground, so I can calculate my max reach in the air. I will change it accordingly.

Comment: Weapon is almost irrelevant, since *any* attacks (including unarmed ones) have 5ft reach for a PC, unless the attack is made with a "reach" weapon, in this case your reach becomes 10ft. What you're asking (I guess) is what is vertical reach. Is it the same 5/10ft, or something different