# How does the size scale work?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, creature-size

What is the size scale and how does it work in D&D 5e? For example, how big would a huge monster be? I've been trying to scale my monsters probably, but I keep finding contradictory information and I don't own the Monster Manual. I'll try to get it when I can.

If, as an example, I have an adolescent dragon with a given wingspan, how do I know what size it should be? How much of its size is wingspan? Is the size only the height, or is it its all-around size?

Comment: Can you give an example of what creature is giving you this problem, and what you're trying to do with the scale? Also, some info on what counter information you're getting would be helpful.

Comment: Are you asking about the size categories or about 'actual' creature size vs the 'size' they are listed as?

Comment: ok, let me give an example if I want to give a phoenix a size how big would it be? like a boss phoenix that is about the size of an adolescent dragon. hopefully, this explained instead of making it worse.

Comment: Still kind of confused myself, but have you read the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters) and the sections on monsters? If not, please review and return with an updated question if you still have one.

Comment: @Catofdoom2 For the example; why not just use an adolescent dragon? There's some other stuff mixed up with D&D phoenixes. Are you then looking for how to get/use height, wingspan, length, etc. to connect with the size scale?

Comment: @Someone_Evil yes, how much of its size is wingspan? is the size only the height, or is it its all-around size? I think I'm more just over-thinking this than anything.

Comment: (It may also help to workshop this question--or just your problem--in [chat]. Many dnd5e experts are almost always to be found there!)

Comment: Related on [Can you fly over a medium creature in a 10' corridor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/121080/can-you-fly-over-a-medium-enemy-creature-in-a-10ft-tall-corridor)

Comment: More to fellow users: what details or clarity is still being sought? (I'm choosing to ask this before clearing out comments and rather than reopening it on my own)

Comment: @Someone_Evil I don't think that we should reopen this q -reasoning  as detailed here https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5274/44723

Answer (score 5):

There's a little table in the Monster Manual, in the first chapter that explains how stats work. It also gives the space that monsters take up on the battlefield. It's on page 6 of the book.

The spaces are as follows:

Tiny: 2.5 by 2.5ft

Small: 5 by 5ft

Medium: 5 by 5ft

Large: 10 by 10ft

Huge: 15 by 15ft

Gargantuan: 20 by 20ft or larger.

In the case of Gargantuan, the monster's description might contain more information about how big it really is. The Tarrasque for example is described as being "70 feet long and 50 feet wide" and so would probably require something like a 100 by 100ft space to fight comfortably.

This same table is also in the Player's Handbook on page 191 along with a bit of extra info on what "Size/Space" actually mean.

This is, of course, information for how big the monsters are on a battlemap. For the actual physical size of a specific creature, you'd have to check their description. It might give you some info, or if not, you'll have to make a ruling on it (maybe by looking at something comparably sized that *does* have a listed size.)

Comment: what if their taller then they are wide?

Answer (score 5):

#### Consult the Size Categories Table in the *Monster Manual* (p. 6) or the *Player's Handbook* (p. 191).

The *Monster Manual* defines creature size as:

> how much space a creature of a particular size controls in combat.

| Size | Space |
| --- | --- |
| Tiny | 2.5 × 2.5 ft |
| Small | 5 × 5 ft |
| Medium | 5 × 5 ft |
| Large | 10 × 10 ft |
| Huge | 15 × 15 ft |
| Gargantuan | 20 × 20 ft or larger |

A creature's Size category does not directly define its physical size, rather it defines the area that it controls in combat. A horse is size Large, but obviously horses are not 10 feet long by 10 feet wide. And on the other end of that, a Gargantuan creature has no upper bound to how big it can be - it may control far more than a 20-ft.-by-20-ft. area in combat.

The [Size section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Size) of the basic rules contains this info as well.